# SSRS Expression still returns a count for all fields

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

Would anyone be able to help me with my SSRS expression? It seems to be returning a count for all records even though I have certain requirements in my `iif` function.

Here is what I currently have:

```
=Count(Iif((Fields!METHOD.Value = "Something") AND (Fields!CATEGORIZATION.Value = "Incident") AND (Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Phone"), Fields!MONTH.Value = 1, 0))
```

The idea is to return a `1` and count it for each record that meets these requirements. If anyone needs me to elaborate any further, please let me know and I will edit/comment on your questions.

Comment: Probably needs to be a `Sum`, not a `Count`.

Comment: @IanPreston - Replacing `Count` with `Sum` results in an error: `uses a numeric aggegate function on data that is not numeric`. any other ideas?

Comment: OK, I had to chance to have a proper look... Please see answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the earlier comment, this should be a `Sum` and not `Count` - the latter simply counts the non-null values, so will always give the same result no matter what the `IIf` returns.

You also don't need `Fields!MONTH.Value = 1` - just return either `1` or `0` in the `IIf` is enough:

```
=Sum(
  Iif(
    (Fields!METHOD.Value = "Something")
      AND (Fields!CATEGORIZATION.Value = "Incident")
      AND (Fields!SOURCE.Value = "Phone")
    , 1
    , 0
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i just saw this elsewhere and tried it and it worked. thanks again!